# Java Android: how to increment a chronometer by 2 seconds after you clicked a button?

Tags: java, android

I'm working to an app which requires a chronometer, and I can't find a solution to increment it by 2 seconds each time I click a button

```
//chronometer session
//private Chronometer chronometer;
//private boolean isRunning;
//private long pauseOffset;

//...

    public void StartChronometer(){
        if(!isRunning){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
            chronometer.start();
            isRunning = true;
        }

    }

    public void PauseChronometer(){
        if(isRunning){
            chronometer.stop();
            pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            isRunning = false;
        }

    }

    public void ResetChronometer(){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        pauseOffset = 0;

    }

    public void IncrementByTwo(){
        if(!isRunning){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
   //????????????????????? NO IDEA ????????????????????????

        }
    }
```

I don't have any idea how to increment it, I need a new chronometer to add in background, and when I click a button to call the function IncrementByTwo and maybe that is all? 2 chronometers, one live, one in background, and somehow to add the second one each time I click the button (absurd or I don't know)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable that counts how many times the button have been clicked and since `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` returns the number of nanoseconds since the application started, you can add `2000000000 * <your_variable>` (2000000000 nanoseconds => 2 seconds) to add your seconds:

```
private int i = 0;

// ...
public void PauseChronometer(){
    if(isRunning){
        chronometer.stop();
        pauseOffset = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (i * 2000000000)) - chronometer.getBase();
        isRunning = false;
    }
}

 public void ResetChronometer(){
    i = 0;
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    pauseOffset = 0;
}

public void IncrementByTwo(){
     if(!isRunning){
         i++;
         chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (i * 2000000000));
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I tried this:                                                                                          `private long i= 0;`
`private double twoSeconds = 2000000000f;`                                                            `if(!isRunning){
            i++;
            chronometer.setBase((long) (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (i* twoSeconds )));
        } `

Comment: @ajroh I've edited the answer so that the offset would still work and to reset `i` in `ResetChronometer()`, but if `chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (i * 2000000000))` is not working that's not going to help...